# How to determine the unramified character corresponding to an unramified Langlands parameter?

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups, p-adic-groups

Let $F$ be a p-adic field with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}$. Let $\textbf{G}$ be a connected split reductive algebraic group over $F$. For simplicity, we assume that $\textbf{G}$ is a Chevalley group. Let $G=\textbf{G}(F)$ and $K=\textbf{G}(\mathcal{O})$. Let $B=TU$ be a fixed Borel subgroup with torus $T$. Let $\hat G$ be the Langlands dual group of $G$ and $\hat T$ be the dual torus. Let $W_F$ be the Weil group of $F$. Let $\varphi: W_F\rightarrow \hat T\rightarrow \hat G$ be an unramified Langlands parameter. Then associated with $\varphi$, by Satake isomorphism, there is an irreducible spherical representation $\pi(\varphi)$ of $G$. It is known that $\pi(\varphi)$ is a sub-quotient of a principal series representation $\textrm{Ind}_{TU}^G(\mu)$.

$\textbf{Question}$: How to determine $\mu$ in terms of $\varphi$?

If $\textbf{G}=\textrm{GL}_n$, my understanding is as follows. An unramified Langlands parameter $\varphi:W_F\rightarrow \hat T$ is determined by its image of $\textrm{Fr}$. Suppose that $\varphi(\textrm{Fr})=\textrm{diag}(a_1,\dots,a_r)\in \hat T$ with $a_i\in \mathbb{C}^\times$. Then the corresponding $\mu:T\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$ is determined by $\mu(1,\dots,1,\varpi,1,\dots,1)=a_i$, where $\varpi$ is a uniformizer of $F$ in the $i$-th position.

Here is one example I am interested in. Define $J_n\in \textrm{GL}_n$ inductively by 
$$J_n=\begin{pmatrix} &1\\ J_{n-1}&\end{pmatrix}, J_1=(1).$$
 Let $G$ be the split $\textrm{SO}_5$, which is defined by the matrix $J_5$. Then $\hat G=\textrm{Sp}_4(\mathbb{C})$, which is realized by the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} &J_2\\ -J_2&\end{pmatrix}.$$
Let $\varphi:W_F\rightarrow \hat T$ by $\varphi(w)=\textrm{diag}(1,|w|,|w|^{-1},1)$. Then what is the corresponding $\mu$?

Any comments and references about the general case or the above special example are appreciated.

Comment: Let $f$ be a continuous compactly supported function on $K \backslash G / K$ . Because $\pi$ is unramified, $f$ acts on $\pi$ with some eigenvalue. To calculate this, we can look at its action on the first basis vector of the induced representation, i.e. the vector on which $TU$ acts by the character $\mu$. The action of $f$ on this vector is multiplication by $\int_{TU} f \mu$, so this must be the eigenvalue.

Comment: On the other hand, the eigenvalue is calculated by applying the Satake transform to $f$, obtaining a function on the maximal torus, converting it to a character of the maximal torus of the dual group, and plugging in $\varphi$. If you look at the definition of the Satake transform, it's similar to this integral, and then the torus to maximal torus conversion shouldn't be hard either...